# Como realizar operações com números realmente grandes em C/C++?

Tags: c, c++, ubuntu, bigint

Como realizar operações de soma com números realmente grandes?
Números que podem chegar a 50 ou 1000 dígitos.

É necessário instalar alguma biblioteca?
Como instalar essa biblioteca no ubuntu?

Tem como postar algum exemplo do código somando os dois valores abaixo?

35398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586
+
17423706905851860660448207621209813287860733969412

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar uma lib para trabalhar com números muito grandes, no Ubuntu sugiro o [GMP](https://gmplib.org/). Instale o GMP com apt-get install libgmp-dev.

Um exemplo de soma utilizando libgmp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>
// Compile com: 
// gcc -lgmp -lm -o add_ex add_ex.c
int main()
{
    mpz_t a, b, soma;
    mpz_init_set_str(a, "35398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586", 10);
    mpz_init_set_str(b, "17423706905851860660448207621209813287860733969412", 10);
    mpz_add (soma, a, b); 
    mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, a); 
    printf("\n + \n");
    mpz_out_str(stdout, 10,b); 
    printf("\n = \n");
    mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, soma);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

O output:

```
35398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586
 +
17423706905851860660448207621209813287860733969412
 =
52822371278678973314278194861994286341050838262998
```